# Please review answers on this popular question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[What is the fastest way for a robot with superhuman capabilities to make money?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48015/what-is-the-fastest-way-for-a-robot-with-superhuman-capabilities-to-make-money) has, so far, 38 answers.  (Did you know there's an auto-flag for "more than 30 answers"?)  On a quick scan most of them look good, though it looks like there might be some overlap.  I see two that are about mining bitcoins, for example; I'm not sure if they're effectively duplicates.

Could the community please take a look at the answers there?  Is everything ok, or are there answers that need to be de-duplicated, expanded, or otherwise improved?

Comment: So what do we do about answers that are dups, or just plain wrong? Previously that’s  ot cause for deletion, only downvoting.

Comment: @JDługosz for dupes, if they weren't posted around the same time -- that is, if one was already there before the other probably started writing -- then I usually comment on the newer one to point out the older one and ask the later answerer to distinguish his answer in some way.  Some people will, upon discovering they've duplicated a prior answer, delete theirs themselves.  SE doesn't seem to have solid guidance on this; best I could find was [this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1096/162102).

Comment: As for answers that are just plain wrong, downvote + comment is the usual response.

Comment: there are lot of good answers, I upvoted 31 answer here from 40 current given. It's just nature of that question, any human activity is applicable to that robot. Answers are pretty divergent, and I would not say that they repeat each other in bad way, there are some intersections, but they have some additional valid points too.

Comment: @MolbOrg thanks for reviewing!

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few on gambling. At least 3 that I have found. Should I do anything to them or not?

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/48032/17720

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/48020/17720

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/48129/17720

Second possibly dupe of third.

Comment: The main question is whether they add anything different to each other or if they are actually duplicates with one adding nothing.

Comment: The second link doesn't really add anything different from the third.

Comment: @Bellerephon totally different answers second talks about actually any type of sport and sport like activity, third more specific about casino gaming. Or we do have some casino games in Olympics?

Answer (score 2):

I think it needs a (community wiki) summary that’s just a bullet list of ideas noted already.  Cool if it linked to which answers mention them, but I don’t expect anyone to do that work.